# Want to print the parent node into a recyclerview from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

```
      FirebaseRecyclerOptions<RestaurantDetails> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<RestaurantDetails>()
                        .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Restaurant").child("Category"), RestaurantDetails.class)
                        .build();

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CategoryAdapter.CategoryViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull RestaurantDetails model) {
        String post_key = getRef(position).getKey();

        holder.restaurant_CategoryList.setText(post_key);

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CategoryAdapter.CategoryViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.restaurant_filter,parent, false);
        return new CategoryViewHolder(view);
    }

    class CategoryViewHolder  extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView  restaurant_CategoryList;

        public CategoryViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            restaurant_CategoryList = itemView.findViewById(R.id.restaurant_Filter);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

I want to print the post_key on my recyclerview but it only shows an empty page. Only white screen. There's no error but I believe I am missing something. I want to only display the Categories. If I use the other node which is "Info" it will print a duplicate of category. For example, Cafe, cafe which I only required word being preview

I have updated the post. Here's my RestaurantDetails.

```
public class RestaurantDetails {
    private String name;
    private String location;
    private String address;
    private String category;
    private String image;
    private Double latitude;
    private Double longitude;
    private Boolean filter;

public RestaurantDetails(String name, String location, String address, String category, String image, Double latitude, Double longitude, Boolean filter) {
    this.name = name;
    this.location = location;
    this.address = address;
    this.category = category;
    this.image = image;
    this.latitude = latitude;
    this.longitude = longitude;
    this.filter = filter;
}
```

}

[image]

Comment: Could you share RestaurantDetails? Why don't you use the 'model'.

Comment: I want to print the list of Category without the duplication of the value preview on Recyclerview. So if I use the 'model' I will print out duplications. Also I have updated the post

Comment: Your query is different with the model

Comment: So I need to make another model for the Category node?

Comment: Yes, you should do

Comment: When I create the new model, I should be able to use the same query with the new model to print out the node key?

Comment: Yes, you can use the same query, only change model.

Comment: I have created the new model but somehow I still can't print out the node key in the recyclerview

Comment: Could I see your code.

Comment: you mean the new model or my Category Adapter?

Comment: all of them, the final form

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211461/discussion-between-i-z-and-kasim-ozdemir).

Comment: Your categoryModel should be private Map<Integer, Boolean> filter;
Because there are many child in a node

Answer (score 0):

Inside your onBindViewHolder() you need to run a loop to get all the keys and print them.

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Restaurant");
        Query query1 = databaseReference1.child("Category");
        query1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String post_key = dataSnapshot1.getKey();
                    System.out.println(post_key);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: I want to print it on the recyclerviewlist. For the time being, I'm encountering another issue cause of the CatagoryModel as I have this issue

No properties to serialize found on class - for private Map

Model does not define a no-argument constructor. If you are using ProGuard, make sure these constructors are not stripped. - for public Map

I was suggested by Kasim to use private Map<Integer, Boolean> filter; but I'm encountering some issues